# How to integrate $\int_{1}^{3} {\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^4 + 1}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{1}^{3} {\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^4 + 1}}\, dx$$

Well, I can simplify the numerator:

$$\int_{1}^{3} {\frac{(x - 1)(x+1)}{x^4 + 1}}\, dx$$

But I have no idea how to simplify the denumenator:

$$\ x^4+1=? \ $$

How to solve this integral?

Comment: $x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(x\sqrt2)^2=(x^2-x\sqrt2+1)(x^2+x\sqrt2+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will first compute the integral without bounds. Start off by rewriting the integral using partial fractions:
$$\int \frac{-2\sqrt{2}x - 2}{4(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1)} + \frac{2 - 2\sqrt{2}x}{4(-x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 1)} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$
Note that we can split this into two integrals to get
$$\int \frac{-2\sqrt{2}x - 2}{4(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1)}\ \mathrm{d}x + \int \frac{2 - 2\sqrt{2}x}{4(-x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 1)} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$
Factoring out the constants on both sides, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{\sqrt{2} - 2x}{-x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 1}\ \mathrm{d}x +
\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{-2\sqrt{2}x - 2}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x +1} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$
Now, make the change of variable
$$ u = -x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 1 \qquad \therefore \qquad \mathrm{d}u = (\sqrt{2} - 2x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
Hence, rewriting the integrand, we have
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{u}\ \mathrm{d}u +
\frac{1}{4} \int -\frac{\sqrt{2}(2x + \sqrt{2})}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x +1} \ \mathrm{d}x,$$
which is the same as writing
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{u}\ \mathrm{d}u -
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{2x + \sqrt{2}}{x^2 + \sqrt{2}x +1} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$
We can do a similar change of variable here by letting
$$ s = x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1 \qquad \therefore \qquad \mathrm{d}s = (\sqrt{2} + 2x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
This gives
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{u}\ \mathrm{d}u -
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{s} \ \mathrm{d}s.$$
It is now easy to integrate both sides and substitute $u$ and $s$ back after integration. You should obtain

$$ \int \frac{x^2 - 1}{x^4+1} \ \mathrm{d}x = 
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \left[\log(-x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 1) - \log(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x + 1)\right] + C,$$
for some constant $C$. It now remains to integrate from $1$ to $3$, which should be a straightforward task from here.

Comment: +1 for a nicely explained computation.  Is there any intuition (something one could see before carrying out the computation) as to why you get logarithms, i.e. why the partial fraction decomposition for this particular fraction works out so that each resulting fraction has the numerator equal to the derivative of the denominator, up to a constant factor?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce, not really. My first guess was partial fractions. While computing the partial fraction form, I realized that the numerator was very similar to the derivative of the denominator, so it looked like I was heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ is finite & non-zero,

$${\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^4 + 1}}=\frac{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}}=\frac{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}{\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)^2-2} $$

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), set $\displaystyle x+\dfrac1x=\sqrt2\sec u$

Comment: @justso, how about this?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\int_1^3\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^3\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^2-2x^2}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_1^3\left[\frac{-1/2+x/\sqrt2}{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}
+\frac{-1/2-x/\sqrt2}{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}\right]\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&={\Large\int}_1^3\left[\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(x-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)}{\left(x-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\frac12}
-\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(x+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)}{\left(x+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\frac12}\right]\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\left[\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\left(x-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\tfrac12\right)
-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\left(x+\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\tfrac12\right)\right]_1^3\tag{4}\\
&=\left[\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}\right)
\right]_1^3\tag{5}\\
&=\left[\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)^2}{x^4+1}\right)
\right]_1^3\tag{6}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{2(10-3\sqrt2)^2}{82(2-\sqrt2)^2}\right)\tag{7}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{57+28\sqrt2}{41}\right)\tag{8}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: break the denominator into a difference of squares
$(2)$: using the factorization from $(1)$, do partial fractions
$(3)$: complete the squares in the denominators and adjust the numerators
$(4)$: integrate
$(5)$: expand the squares and combine the logarithms
$(6)$: neaten up the denominator
$(7)$: plug in the limits
$(8)$: simplify the argument to $\log$

Comment: I just ran this through Mathematica as a check, and it gives the same form.